# Displaying PDF , Richfaces

Tags: jsf, pdf, richfaces

How can I display a PDF document on a rich:popupPanel. I am trying to display PDF document  in a popup from a view scoped JSF page.

**Issue faced** : Parent page stops working when I click on the h:commandLink which fires a new view to display the PDF

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Did you find any better?

Comment: No, I didn't, still looking for an option other than the IFRAME approach

Comment: Don't know why you don't want to use it, but it looks like it isn't a JSF (and like I said in my answer, I'm affraid, that you have to use pure web's posibilities and skip JSF).  See f.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know is to use HTML directly. You can use `IFRAME` or `OBJECT`.

So just put something like this in your `rich:popupPanel`:

```
<rich:panel>
    <iframe src="path_to_your_file/sample.pdf" 
    class="pdfFrame" width="800" height="1000" scrolling="no" />
</rich:panel>
```

I don't think there's a way to do this with *pure* JSF tags. The same way is presented on [PrimeFaces's showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml):

```
<h3>PDF</h3>
<object type="application/pdf"    
        data="/showcase/resources/demo/media/guide.pdf?pfdrid_c=true" 
        height="300px" width="100%" internalinstanceid="3">

    Your browser can't display pdf,
    <a href="/resources/demo/media/guide.pdf">click</a>
    to download pdf instead.
</object>
```